# Как в битриксе в готовом решении аспро включить обновление цены при выборе торгового предложения

Tags: php, битрикс

Помогите с решением проблемы, установил решение Аспро лайтшоп настроил вывод торгового предложения, но цена в карточке не меняется,  при клике на граммы и вид упаковки цена не меняется и в корзину добавляется товар с наименьшими граммами и ценой
[image: вот вариант торгового предложения]

Comment: А цена для каждого торгового предложения указана?

Comment: @TemirStack все верно

Comment: Возможно это поможет [Типы цен для торговых предложений](https://aspro.ru/docs/course/course46/lesson2302/)